# Porting Pyrhon CMS from Apache to Nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, content-management-system, uwsgi

I've written a simple CMS in Python.  It currently runs on Apache, and it consists of a bunch of python scripts in /usr/lib/cgi-bin.  I'm trying to get the CMS working in Nginx.  I've never used Nginx before, so I'd appreciate some input from anyone who's familiar with it.

I'd like to run the CMS without having to modify it - ideally I'd like to be able use the CMS with Apache and Nginx, and I don't want to maintain two separate versions.

The main script is /usr/lib/cgi-bin/pyindex.py.  I've set up two locations in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/dir.html /cgi-bin/pyindex.py?q=$uri;
}

location /cgi-bin/ {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

I installed uwsgi and uwsgi-plugin-python and set up /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/mydomainname.com.xml as follows:

```
<uwsgi>
    <plugin>python</plugin>
    <plugin>cgi</plugin>
    <socket>127.0.0.1:8080</socket>
    <chdir>/usr/lib/cgi-bin/</chdir>
    <pythonpath>/usr/lib/cgi-bin/</pythonpath>
    <module>pyindex.py</module>
    <cgi>/cgi-bin=/usr/lib/cgi-bin/</cgi>
    <cgi-allowed-ext>.py</cgi-allowed-ext>
    <master/>
    <processes>4</processes>
    <harakiri>60</harakiri>
    <reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
    <cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
    <stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
    <max-requests>2000</max-requests>
    <limit-as>512</limit-as>
    <reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
    <reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
    <no-orphans/>
    <vacuum/>
</uwsgi>
```

When I point my browser at any dynamic page, I see this error message:

> uWSGI Error
>
> Python application not found

So it looks like nginx is successfully passing requests to uwsgi, but uwsgi isn't set up correctly.

The log in /var/log/uwsgi/app/mydomainname.com.log shows that pyindex.py runs when uwsgi starts up, and falls over because the QUERY_STRING environment variable isn't available.  The script doesn't get executed when a request is passed from nginx to uwsgi.

Is there a way to set this up so that pyindex.py isn't executed on start up, but executes when uwsgi receives a request from nginx?

I'm using Nginx v 1.2.1, uwsgi 1.2.3, Python 2.7 on Raspbian.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the uWSGI python plugin, you do not need it.

You need the CGI plugin:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html

Comment: That's fixed it.  I also had to upgrade to the latest version of uWSGI.